# Not able to authenticate Google Account in Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, google-oauth, spyder

I am trying to run `read_gbq` in spyder python script using Spyder, I am able to click on the authorize URL and paste the Authorization code, but after pressing shift+enter it goes into `bad handshake`. Any help will be appreciated.

Attached are screenshots for the same:

Python Code used in spyder :

```
import pandas_gbq
import pandas as pd
project_id ='<'project_id'>
sql = 'select * from <datasetname.tablename> limit 10'

df = pandas_gbq.read_gbq(sql,project_id,reauth=True,dialect='standard')
print('DONE Connecting with BQ')
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`pandas-gbq` authenticates with the [Google BigQuery service via OAuth 2.0](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/). Use the [credentials](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.credentials.html#google.auth.credentials.Credentials) argument to explicitly pass in Google Credentials.

If the credentials parameter is not set, pandas-gbq tries the following authentication method:

In-memory, cached credentials at `pandas_gbq.context.credentials`. These credentials are automatically cached in memory by calls to `pandas_gbq.read_gbq()` and `pandas_gbq.to_gbq()`. To manually set the credentials, construct an `google.auth.credentials.Credentials` object and set it as the context credentials as demonstrated in the example below. See [auth documentation](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#obtaining-credentials) for more information on obtaining credentials.

```
import pandas_gbq
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    '/path/to/key.json',
)
pandas_gbq.context.credentials = credentials
pandas_gbq.context.project = "your-project-id"

# The credentials and project_id arguments can be omitted.
df = pandas_gbq.read_gbq("SELECT my_col FROM `my_dataset.my_table`")
```

I believe that the issue could come from the fact that Google credentials must be specifically passed in using the credentials argument. Follow pandas-gbq [authentication documentation](https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/authentication.html).

Comment: this example leverages service_account credentials, in my current scenario I cannot create service account credentials due to lack of permission.Will it be possible to provide username/password of google account in json and pass it on to credentials parameter ?

Comment: There are a few that lead to this and none of them are the fault of library. I would check, in no particular order: 1. Python version, 2. version of openssl, older versions can lack SNI support, 3. version of requests and certifi. You can try installing `requests[security]` to see if it automatically fixes it. Some VMs include very old SSL root certificates which need to get updated, for example (sometimes updated SSL on server resolve the issue). JSON private key file is used only with service account https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.html#google.auth.default